# Simple supervised training algorithm

Tags: c#, artificial-intelligence

I am seraching for a simple supervised training algorithm that finds best values for some variables based on a training input set. (training input set is a set of inputs with a desired output for each of them)

My best values are some `double` values that gives me maximum correct answers from training input set.

And the variables should be used in some `if...else` conditions.

here is a very simple example:

a b o

---

1 1 1

0 1 0

1 0 0

0 0 0

in which line, first and second values (a,b) are input and the third value (o) is desired output.

and if I have just one condition like this:

```
if ((a > d1) && (b > d2)
    return 1;
else
    return 0;
```

In this example, I want to find the best values of d1 and d2 to get less wrong answers from the training set.

So, in this example the d1 and d2 values are should be something bigger than 0 and lower than 1.

But my real problem is a little harder than this example.

What algorithm do you suggest for me?

Answer (score 0):

You can hook up a simple neural network (An MLP) and train it using backpropagation.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilayer_perceptron

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation

Comment: I know that, but I'm searching for a simpler solution that optimizes d1 and d2 to get the best values "with some if...else conditions".

Comment: Ah, I was thinking you wanted to do an offline search for optimal d1, d2 and then use those weights in your hard coded if/else.

Comment: almost I want to do that, but just with if/else , not with a backpropagation. I just want d1, d2, d3, ... for my if/else conditions, not as weights.

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough information in your question to suggest a good general-purpose solution. Knowing the source of the data might help. Still, here is a simple thing you can do:

- Take a square image.
- Draw each data point, using the two input values as the coordinates and the output as colour.
- Note whether there is a pattern in the image.
- Approximate the pattern with code.